# Dynamics Crm 2011 - Dashboard Auto-Refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking for a way to access the operation the dashboard ribbon calls when refresh all is clicked. So I can use it to auto-refresh a specific dashboard made up of girds.

It cannot be a full-screen dashboard as the ribbon is needed to work with some of the data in the girds. When I was doing my initial research this seemed like the most popular method but due to the dependency on the ribbon it doesn't work for me.

The second means I found of getting this done was to alter the refresh all in the ribbon, but I don't want to make the auto refresh available globally.

The closest solution I could find was to add a web part to the dashboard with the following JavaScript.

```
setTimeout("parent.location.reload(true);", 20000);
```

While this works it's a bit jarring when the whole dashboard disappears as it reloads. So I was hoping there was a way to refresh a dashboard from a web part in the same manner the girds refresh when you click refresh all in the ribbon or the refresh icon in a grid.

Surprisingly I wasn't able to find too much info on this. `AppGridWebService.ashx?operation=Refresh` is what is called when refresh is clicked.